# Calling custom middleware from a service

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to add a custom middleware to a service following this [information](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware). This is my code:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  function retrieveConnInfo(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req, res);
    next();
  }

  const options = {
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  app.use('/actions', retrieveConnInfo, createService(options));

  const service = app.service('actions');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working the way you expect?  Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors, the custom middleware doesn't get called.

Comment: @nidkil that custom middleware will be called, given that the client is using rest but with socketio, it does not. So try requesting via rest and see how it goes.

Comment: You are right. I was calling the service from another service. I guess I will need to move the middleware to app.js and run it for all services. Bummer. Thx for your help.

Comment: @jalil do you know how I can setup a middleware that will be called after every request received by Exprees but before Feathers kicks in?

Comment: Express middleware will not run when you are using a websocket connection.

Comment: @daff I'm not using websockets. I'm using test and want to get the users IP address. Any suggestions how to setup the middleware? Just out of interest how would you do this if running websockets?

Comment: Stupid auto correct: test=rest :-)